# Oozie workflow warning - "The application does not define formal parameters in its XML definition"

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

What is the meaning of the org.apache.oozie.util.ParameterVerifier warning "The application does not define formal parameters in its XML definition" ?

Comment: can u post your workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to your workflow.xml or coordinator.xml not containing a child node for "parameters".

The Oozie code for this check can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/util/ParameterVerifier.java).

You can find an example (second code section) [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters).

Note: It appears that this is a benign warning ... unless these parameters are required for something else.